# How to upload file to AWS bucket with AWS Java SDK 2

Tags: amazon-s3

- AWS Java SDK 2.15.73 (Current latest version).
- Java 1.8.222
- Operating system  IBM AIX 7.1

Developing an application that uploads a file to S3 bucket.

**In Maven pom file:**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.73</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>apache-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-preview-10</version>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>http-client-spi</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-preview-10</version>
    </dependency>           
</dependencies>
```

**Beginning of Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in sendFileToAWSNoAuth=Unable to marshall request to JSON: baseUri must not be null.
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to marshall request to JSON: baseUri must not be null.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:98)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.transform.PutObjectRequestMarshaller.marshall(PutObjectRequestMarshaller.java:53)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.transform.PutObjectRequestMarshaller.marshall(PutObjectRequestMarshaller.java:31)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.runtime.transform.StreamingRequestMarshaller.marshall(StreamingRequestMarshaller.java:48)
```

**Java code:**

Authentication is needed and execution thru proxy server.

```
String endPointURL = appParms.getProxyServer() + ":" + appParms.getProxyServerPort();

URI endPointUri = new URI(endPointURL); 

ProxyConfiguration proxyConfig = ProxyConfiguration.builder()
        .endpoint(endPointUri)
        .build();

SdkHttpClient httpClient =
        ApacheSdkHttpClientFactory.builder()
                .proxyConfiguration(proxyConfig)
                .build()
                .createHttpClient();

ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProfile = ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().profileName(appParms.getProfileName()).build();

Region region = Region.EU_CENTRAL_1;
S3Client s3NonEncryption = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProfile)
            .region(region)
            .endpointOverride(endPointUri)
            .httpClient(httpClient)
            .build();
            
String folderKey = appParms.getBucketFolder() + "/" + appParms.getFileName();

File aFile = new File(appParms.getFilePath() + "/" + appParms.getFileName());

PutObjectRequest putOb = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(appParms.getBucketNameSSE())
            .key(folderKey)
            .build();
    
PutObjectResponse response = s3NonEncryption.putObject(putOb, aFile.toPath());
```

Exception occurs in this last line (`s3NonEncryption.putObject`)

Answer (score 1):

This `Base URI must not be null` error was caused by `endpointOverride(endPointUri)` in `S3Client.builder`. ..

Also in http client creation was used class `ApacheSdkHttpClientFactory` that caused all kind of class mismatch error in run.

Correct way is to to use class `ApacheHttpClient`:

```
SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder()
  .proxyConfiguration(proxyConfig)
  .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(30000))
  .build();
```

Still there is timeout error in execution.

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to bdw-landing-sse-test-s3.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 [bdw-landing-sse-test-s3.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/52.219.72.81] failed: connect timed out
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:98)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:43)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:198)
```